# C-Read txt into txt file

Tags: c, arrays

I have a txt document test.txt in directory "/user/doc" like this:

```
10 21 34 45 29 38 28
29 47 28 32 31 29 20 12 24
```

*Two lines of numbers separated by "space".

I want to write the numbers into a 2-row array, with flexible length. The length may depends on the amount of more numbers in one line of the txt document. In the example it should be 9.

And after that the array may look like:

```
10 21 34 45 29 38 28 0 0
29 47 28 32 31 29 20 12 24
```

Numbers in line-1 are in row-1 in the array. And numbers in line-2 are in row-2 in the array.

I got the code below to fill the array one by one but I don't know how to modify it to what I need. Can anybody help? Thanks!

```
FILE *fp;
int key1[2][10];

if((fp = fopen("/Users/doc/test.txt", "rt")) == NULL)
{
    printf("\nCannot open file");
    exit(1);
}

else
{
    while(!feof(fp))
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        { 
            for(int j = 0; j < 10 ;j++)
            {
                fscanf(fp, "%d", &key1[i][j]); 
            }
        }

    }
}

fclose(fp);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int getColCount(FILE *fin){
    long fpos = ftell(fin);
    int count = 0;
    char buff[BUFSIZ];
    while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fin)){
        char *p;
        for(p=strtok(buff, " \t\n");p;p=strtok(NULL, " \t\n"))
            ++count;
        if(count)break;
    }
    fseek(fin, fpos, SEEK_SET);
    return count;
}

int main(void){
    FILE *fp;
    int *key1[2];

    if((fp = fopen("/Users/doc/test.txt", "rt")) == NULL){
        printf("\nCannot open file");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i){
        int size = getColCount(fp);
        key1[i] = malloc((size+1)*sizeof(int));
        if(key1[i]){
            key1[i][0] = size;//length store top of row
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "It was not possible to secure the memory.\n");
            exit(2);
        }
        for(int j = 1; j <= size ;++j){
            fscanf(fp, "%d", &key1[i][j]); 
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    {//check print and dealocate
        for(int i = 0; i < 2 ; ++i){
            for(int j = 1; j <= key1[i][0]; ++j)
                printf("%d ", key1[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
            free(key1[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read each line one by one with [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) then split them with [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) and parse with [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol).

Something like this:

```
char line[256];
int l = 0;
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), input_file))
{
    int n = 0;

    for (char *ptr = strtok(line, " "); ptr != NULL; ptr = strtok(NULL, " "))
    {
        key1[l][n++] = strtol(ptr, NULL, 10);
    }

    l++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But one more question, where should I initial the array key1 here?

Comment: @JiayiGuo You can do it at declaration, like `int key1[2][10] = { { 0 } };`

Comment: What happens if fgets stops mid-number? For example, your line contains `... 1 14 31 12 ...` and the first loop iteration puts `... 1 14 3` into `line` and the second puts `1 12 ...` into `line`.

Comment: @RyanAmos The `fgets` function can only stop mid-line if the file ends there or there is a read-error (and in the last case it will return `NULL` thereby stopping the loop). If `fgets` doesn't return `NULL` it has read a complete line, if the numbers stops unexpectedly then its an error in the file (i.e. a newline that shouldn't be there).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg if the line exceeds the size of `line`, what happens?