# C-Read txt and write into array

Tags: c

I asked a similar question before, the link is here.
[C-Read txt into txt file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130672/c-read-txt-into-txt-file/18131650?noredirect=1#18131650)

Just found that there was a little problem with the code that the first column of the array was given the value of "size".

I'd like to post a new one here hope anybody can help.

---

I have a txt document in the directory /user/test/key.txt . The content in the txt is like this:

```
10 21 34 45 29 38 28
(blank line)
29 47 28 32 31 29 20 12 24
(blank line)
```

I'd like to read these numbers from the txt and write into a two-line array. The length of the array may vary according to the longer line in the txt.
And it may become like this in the array:

```
10 21 34 45 29 38 28 0 0
29 47 28 32 31 29 20 12 24
```

Thank you!

Comment: So you want the lines of numbers to have the same number of entries as the longest line, padded with 0 entries at the end if needed?

Comment: You should start by writing something and making your best attempt at making it work.

Comment: It should be a minor change from BLUEPIXY's answer in the previous question. If you don't have a max length, you need to read the entire file first to find it. Then just something as simple as `calloc` instead of `malloc` might work. Otherwise loop through the rest and set them to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that's what the answer you've accepted explicitly does and it's a quite good idea because somehow you have to determine how many columns a specific lines contains. 
Another diea would be to let a special value in every row determine the end (like the `'\0'` in strings). To have it like that you can change the code as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int getColCount(FILE *fin){
    long fpos = ftell(fin);
    int count = 0;
    char buff[BUFSIZ];
    while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fin)){
        char *p;
        for(p=strtok(buff, " \t\n");p;p=strtok(NULL, " \t\n"))
            ++count;
        if(count)break;
    }
    fseek(fin, fpos, SEEK_SET);
    return count;
}

int main(void){
    FILE *fp;
    int *key1[2];

    if((fp = fopen("/Users/doc/test.txt", "rt")) == NULL){
        printf("\nCannot open file");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; ++i){
        int size = getColCount(fp);
        // size+1 is still necessary, the additional element is now needed for the delimiting value instead of the number of elements
        key1[i] = malloc((size+1)*sizeof(int));
        /* CHANGE: don't store size in col 0
        if(key1[i]){
            key1[i][0] = size;//length store top of row
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "It was not possible to secure the memory.\n");
            exit(2);
        }
        now we just do: */ 
        if(!key1[i]){
            fprintf(stderr, "It was not possible to secure the memory.\n");
            exit(2);
        }
        /* CHANGE: we start with index 0 */
        //for(int j = 1; j <= size ;++j){
        for(int j = 0; j < size ;++j){
            fscanf(fp, "%d", &key1[i][j]); 
        }
        /* CHANGE: we add a final value to determine the end of the row */
        key[i][size] = -1;   // choose a value that cannot occur in your data
    }
    fclose(fp);
    {//check print and dealocate
        for(int i = 0; i < 2 ; ++i){
            for(int j = 1; j <= key1[i][0]; ++j)
                printf("%d ", key1[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
            free(key1[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Ingo Leonhardt. I made some very little change and it worked.

Comment: tell me and I'm glad to correct the post for the next one who reads it

Comment: @Jiayi Guo please note that `malloc(size+1*sizeof(int))` is still neccessary. I've added a comment in the code to explain why

Comment: @ Ingo Leonhardt. Thank you for your follow up. There's one more question. The test output inside the loop is ok. But outside the loop, since the value of size has been set to the length of second line, is there anyway to get output the two lines in array in a loop? I'd prefer the shorter line is padded with 0. Thank you!

Comment: Don't loop till `j < size` but till `key[i][j] != -1` (or whatever your terminal char is). Padding all lines to the maximum size would be a completely differen approach and would make it neccessary to read the data twice (once for determining the max, once for filling the arrays).